# Java: Paper, Rock, Scissors GUI

Tags: java, swing, enums

My class has been assigned a rock, paper, scissors game. Here is the assignment description:

Learning Objectives :

- Practice the use of enums
- Create an enum that includes constructor(s), field(s), and method(s)
- Design and implement your own GUI
- Create a runnable jar

Description:
Write a program to play Rock Paper Scissors against the computer

Requirements:

- Create an enum that represents the three choices: rock, paper, and
  scissors.

  - Include a field of type ImageIcon (optionally more fields)
  - Include a constructor
  - Include a method that evaluates
- Create a gui application that plays Rock Paper Scissors against the computer

  - Allow the user to select one of the three choices.
  - Once the user has made a selection the computer randomly chooses
    rock, paper, or scissors
  - For both selections the corresponding image is displayed
  - In addition the result is displayed (who beat whom)
  - The user needs to be able to play multiple times without restarting
    the application
  - Create a runnable jar that includes the source code ( 4 points )

*edit

ok, I'm in the home stretch, all that's really needed for the most part is the evaluate() method. Any ideas as to how to go about it? I've been rattling my brain for the last hour and I can't quite figure it out. Anyways, here's the updated code:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public enum RPSChoice {
    ROCK(new ImageIcon(RPSChoice.class.getResource("rock.png"))), 
    PAPER(new ImageIcon(RPSChoice.class.getResource("paper.png"))), 
    SCISSORS(new ImageIcon(RPSChoice.class.getResource("scissors.png")));

        private ImageIcon imgChoice;

        private RPSChoice(ImageIcon imgChoice) {
            this.imgChoice = imgChoice;
        }

        public ImageIcon getImageIcon(){
            return imgChoice;
        }

    public static void evaluate(){
        //TODO
    }

    public static RPSChoice randomChoice(){
        return values()[(int) (Math.random() * values().length)];
    }
}
```

And the gui

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;

    public class RockPaperScissorsGUI extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JPanel humanDisplay = new JPanel();
        private JPanel computerDisplay = new JPanel();
        private JLabel winnerAnnouncement = new JLabel("Winner Shown Here");
        private JPanel choicePanel = new JPanel();

        private RPSChoice rock = RPSChoice.ROCK;
        private RPSChoice paper = RPSChoice.PAPER;
        private RPSChoice scissors = RPSChoice.SCISSORS;

        private RPSChoice randChoice;

        private final JPanel humOrCompPanel = new JPanel();
        private final JLabel lblHuman = new JLabel("Human");
        private final JLabel lblComputer = new JLabel("Computer");
        private JButton btnScissors = new JButton("Scissors");
        private JButton btnPaper = new JButton("Paper");
        private JButton btnRock = new JButton("Rock");

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        RockPaperScissorsGUI frame = new RockPaperScissorsGUI();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public RockPaperScissorsGUI() {
            setTitle("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 544, 366);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            setContentPane(contentPane);

            JPanel choicePanel = addPanels();

            addButtons(choicePanel, rock, btnRock);
            addButtons(choicePanel, paper, btnPaper);
            addButtons(choicePanel, scissors, btnScissors);
        }

        private JPanel addPanels() {
            contentPane.add(humanDisplay, BorderLayout.WEST);
            humanDisplay.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

            contentPane.add(computerDisplay, BorderLayout.EAST);

            winnerAnnouncement.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            contentPane.add(winnerAnnouncement, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            contentPane.add(choicePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            contentPane.add(humOrCompPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            humOrCompPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
            lblHuman.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            humOrCompPanel.add(lblHuman);
            lblComputer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            humOrCompPanel.add(lblComputer);

            return choicePanel;
        }

        private void addButtons(JPanel choicePanel, RPSChoice choice, JButton button ){
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    humanDisplay.removeAll();
                    humanDisplay.add(new JLabel(choice.getImageIcon()));

                    computerDisplay.removeAll();
                    randChoice = RPSChoice.randomChoice();
                    computerDisplay.add(new JLabel(randChoice.getImageIcon()));

                    choicePanel.repaint();
                    choicePanel.revalidate();

                }
            });
            choicePanel.add(button);
        }
    }
```

Thank you everyone for all of the help so far!

Comment: You could use a map (for instance, an `EnumMap<RPSChoice, ImageIcon>`) and initialize it when you load the images.

Comment: I'd suggest you keep the model and the UI separated. Enum value and who beat whom and the random picking of computer's move are the model. The icons and the panel are the UI. Look int Model-View-Controller framework.

Comment: We haven't learned about maps though, unfortunately. I could probably get the UI part done without much of a sweat, but everything in that enum class is just stumping me. As I mentioned, particularly the enums themselves and setting up the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable ImageIcon to the enum, and asociate ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS witch its images:

```
public enum RPSChoice {

    ROCK(new ImageIcon(RPSChoice.class.getResource("rock.png"))), 
    PAPER(new ImageIcon(RPSChoice.class.getResource("paper.png"))), 
    SCISSORS(new ImageIcon(RPSChoice.class.getResource("scissors.png")));

    ImageIcon img;

    private RPSChoice(ImageIcon img) {
        this.img = img; 
    }

    public ImageIcon getImage() {
        return img;
    }

}
```

Comment: Forgive me for sounding so foolish, but where exactly does the variable "Image" come from, in your example? Would that come from my Collection or an entirely new initialization of an image?

Comment: Never mind, I get what you mean now. This is a great start. I can actually start moving forward now. I'll let you know how things go and if further help is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @Godfried23 I have changed the "Image" for the object that you need in each enum variable.

Comment: Nit Pick: `ImageIcon` doesn't provide useful feedback should the images fail to load for some reason and use a background thread to the load images which can sometimes cause odd behavior. Where possible, I'd use `ImageIO.read` instead, but that's just me

Comment: we're forced to use ImageIcon for this project, but I'll certainly try that out on my own after this.